# Intellij - Send arguments using SBT plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I am using a SBT Task to run my code and I want to send some arguments.

Using SBT shell, `run foo bar` works perfectly, but I can't make it work using the SBT Task. Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and tried to put the command in quotes. That worked!

So, just try to put "run foo bar" with quotes in the Tasks field of the Run/Debug Configuration dialog.